# Spreadsheet Gear migration errors

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015, spreadsheetgear

I am migrating  Spreadsheet gear of my application from 6.0.3.190 to 
7.4.1.104.I am getting my issues with Color property.Can any one help me in this.Now I am using `using Color = System.Drawing.Color;` and also `ToSGColor()`.This became very hectic to do in all places where ever we use color.I expect we should have some shortcut to do this.Can any one suggest me How can i get all functionalities with few changes only.I am also getting exceptions to c onvert IColorFormat.LineColor to system.drawing.Color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the "[Breaking Changes](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012_Breaking_Changes.html)" page in the SpreadsheetGear 2012 documentation, which lists this particular change:

- In order to support WPF and Silverlight, the core API has been
  separated from the GDI+ and Windows Forms APIs and therefore uses the
  new [SpreadsheetGear.Color](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Color.html) type rather than
  SpreadsheetGear.Drawing.Color. SpreadsheetGear.Drawing.Color has been
  moved to SpreadsheetGear2012.Drawing.dll.  See
  [SpreadsheetGear.Drawing.Color](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Drawing~SpreadsheetGear.Drawing.Color.html) for an example which uses the implicit
  and static converters to convert between SpreadsheetGear.Color,
  SpreadsheetGear.Drawing.Color and System.Drawing.Color. 
  [SpreadsheetGear.Colors](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Colors.html) and [SpreadsheetGear.SystemColors](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.SystemColors.html) provide
  helpful predefined colors to replace the use of predefined colors in
  System.Drawing.Color.

So you'll need to ensure than any place where you were previously using System.Drawing colors now use SpreadsheetGear.Drawing colors, including API like IColorFormat.LineColor.

There aren't really any "migration" tools to automatically convert such instances to the new API.  So you'll need to resolve these errors for each code file.  Doing a Find/Replace keyword search for "System.Drawing" and "SpreadsheetGear.Drawing" could possibly speed up the process, though this would depend on what `using` statements you have added to each code file.